# How to use multiple values in SIMILAR TO without hardcoding

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column as follows (with imaginary values):

```
<table_name>.<column_name>
a_b
g_c
w_d
k_e
```

I would like to match this column with another column using `SIMILAR TO` operator. Something like:

```
Select *
from <table_name1>
where column_name1 SIMILAR TO '%(<table_name>.<column_name>)%';
```

I know the multiple values in `SIMILAR TO` need to be separated with a pipe operator. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help would be super apreciated.

**EDIT**: I'd need to `JOIN` both these tables coz I'll need one of the columns to `group` on. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify table definition and input data. Either way, don't use `SIMILAR TO`: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.column1 similar to '%('||(SELECT LISTAGG(t1.column1, '|') FROM table1 t1)||')%'
```

Note that I'm using `listagg` for Redshift, but in Postgre it would be `string_agg`.

The `listagg`/`string_agg` will concatenate all the values (first argument) together separated by a pipe (second argument). So `'%('||(SELECT LISTAGG(t1.column1, '|') FROM table1 t1)||')%'` will result in a string like `%(a_b|g_c|w_d|k_e)%` which is what you want for your `similar to` comparison.

An alternative to consider (especially if the values you're matching might be longer than 64K characters and cause issues with `listagg`) might be

```
SELECT distinct t2.* -- Distinct because a row in t2 might match multiple rows in t1
FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1
 on t2.column1 similar to '%('||t1.column1||')%' -- This could just be a normal like if you don't have any special regex besides percent and underscore
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It's very helpful :). Is there any way I can do this in a `join` condition? I'd like a column from the joined table to group on. Currently it says that aggregates are not allowed in `join`.

Comment: Oh, I just read it fully. I will try option 2 which uses a join.

Comment: When I try to run the second version, I get this error: `INFO:  Function "similar_escape(text,text)" not supported.
ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

Comment: Can you try with a `like` instead (will need to remove the brackets)? `on t2.column1 like '%'||t1.column1||'%'`. I tested my answer in Postgre, but not Redshift.